# How to properly ignore case in regex

Tags: r, regex, ignore-case

This is about R.  Can someone look at this:

```
{library(forcats)
x <- filter(gss_cat, rincome != regex("not applicable", ignore_case = TRUE))}
```

The `ignore_case = TRUE` has no effect.  "Not applicable" and "not applicable" still look different to the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this example :

```
df <- data.frame(a = c('This is not applicable', 'But this is applicable', 
                       'This is still NOT aPPLicable'))
```

You need to use `regex` in one of the `stringr` function like `str_detect` here :

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% filter(str_detect(a, regex('not applicable', 
              ignore_case = TRUE), negate = TRUE))

#                      a
#1 But this is applicable
```

Or in base R use `subset` with `grepl`

```
subset(df, !grepl('not applicable', a, ignore.case = TRUE))
```